# two dimensional array fill up with code and description empty in swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I have defined my array in swift like

```
let cList = [[String]]()
```

now i want to fill the array with while getting response country code and country description.
So i can get it at the time of submit the page.

I am fetching my response below:

```
        if let results = jsonResult["country"] as? NSArray
          {
            for country in results {                  {
                let couCode: String? = country["couCode"] as? String
                let couDescription: String?  = country["couDescription"] as? String
                println(couCode,couDescription)

                self.countryList.append(couDescription!)

            }
        }
```

Now from above code how would i fill the two dimension array?

Comment: I would suggest you to create array of dictionary or array of some struct and put the couCode, couDescription into the same structure. That way it will simplify your implementation.

Comment: thanks for the really quick response.... @sandeep...How can i create a global variable for dictionary and store into it...Can you please give me an swift example....so that i can understand..sorry i am new to swift...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var cList = [[String]]()

cList.append(["code1", "description1"])
cList.append(["code2", "description2"])
cList.append(["code3", "description3"])
cList.append(["code4", "description4"])

let towCode:String = "code4"
let towDescription:String = "description4"

for var i:Int = 0; i < cList.count; i++
{
    if towCode == cList[i][0]
    {
        println("towCode found in cList at location \(i)")
        println("towDescription at this location = \(cList[i][1])")
        break;
    }
}

for var i:Int = 0; i < cList.count; i++
{
    if towDescription == cList[i][1]
    {
        println("towDescription found in cList at location \(i)")
        println("towCode found at this location = \(cList[i][0])")
        break;
    }
}
```

Result:

towCode found in cList at location 3

towDescription at this location = description4

towDescription found in cList at location 3

towCode found at this location = code4

If you want to find multiple hits in cList, delete the break statements.

Comment: thanks...thats make my job even easy...i want the towcode value instead of the (location 3) when we check towDescription...How can we get that????

Comment: I am doing this...but i am getting description not the code.....             for var i:Int = 0; i < tList.count; i++
            {
                if txtFieldSelectedTown.text == tList[i][1]
                {
                    println("towDescription found in cList at location \(i)\(tList[i][1]))")
                    break;
                }
            }  Can u please advise me on this????

Comment: I edited the last answer.  I think this demonstrates how to go both ways.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation, for a two dimensional array:

```
var cList = [[String]]()

cList.append(["String1", "String2"])
cList.append(["String3", "String4"])

println("cList = \(cList)")
println("cList[0][0] = \(cList[0][0])")
println("cList[0][1] = \(cList[0][1])")
```

Result:

cList = [[String1, String2], [String3, String4]]

cList[0][0] = String1

cList[0][1] = String2

or:

```
var cList = [[String]]()

cList.append(["String1", "String2", "String5"])
cList.append(["String3", "String4", "String6"])

println("cList = \(cList)")
println("cList[0][0] = \(cList[0][0])")
println("cList[0][1] = \(cList[0][1])")
println("cList[0][2] = \(cList[0][2])")
```

Result:

cList = [[String1, String2, String5], [String3, String4, String6]]

cList[0][0] = String1

cList[0][1] = String2

cList[0][2] = String5

Comment: Thanks....i have implemented it...but it is giving me an error of...Immutable value of type '[([(String)])]' only has mutating members named 'append'...Do u have an idea?

Comment: That's because you declared it with let; declare it with var. var makes a mutable array.

Comment: thanks a lot that worked....one more question...i have store in two dimension array now...But if i want to check the towCode for selected description than how would i check that?any help is appreciated....this is how i stored...   let towCode: String! = town["towCode"] as? String
                    let towDescription: String!  = town["towDescription"] as? String
               
                    self.cList.append([towCode,towDescription])

Comment: I posted another answer.